# XGBoost can't find sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I’m experimenting with XGBoost and am blocked by an error I can’t figure out. I have sklearn installed in the active environment and can verify it by training a sklearn RandomForestClassifier *in the same notebook*. When I try to train a XGBoost model I get the error `XGBoostError: sklearn needs to be installed in order to use this module`

This works:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
```

This throws the exception:

```
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth=3, n_estimators=300, learning_rate=0.05).fit(train_X, train_y)
```

UPDATE: Created a PyCharm module with *exactly* the same code and imports and it executed without an exception. So this appears to be a Jupyter Notebook issue. PyCharm is pointed to the same Anaconda environment as the notebook.

UPDATE 2: Created a *new* notebook and copied the code from the one that was throwing the exception. The code runs OK in the new notebook. Sigh. Case closed.

Comment: Is `sklearn` installed on your system? Will `pip install sklearn` fix the problem?

Comment: what do your import look like? it should be: `form xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier`; also, what version of xgboost are you running?

Comment: I had `import xgboost as xgb` but after reading your question I added `from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier` Still get the error. Anaconda shows Ver 0.7post3 as the xgboost version

Answer (score 11):

Ran into the same issue, I had installed `sklearn` **after** installing `xgboost` **while** my jupyter notebook was running. By restarting my Jupyter notebook server, `xgboost` was able to find the `sklearn` installation.

Tested this in another fresh environment where I've installed `sklearn` **before** installing `xgboost` **then** starting my jupyter notebook without the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with a more complicated project, after releasing a new version suddenly it failed.

luckily in my case, I had docker images for each version, and was able to use `pip freeze` to see what changed.

In both version I used `xgboost==0.81`
In the version that worked I had `scikit-learn==0.21.3` and in the new version it was `scikit-learn==0.22`

surprisingly enough, that's now what caused the issue. I've tried to uninstall and reinstall `xgboost` and reverted `scikit-learn` to the version is was originally on, and still no luck (even after making sure to install one after the other in the right order).

what did cause the issue was an update of `numpy` from `1.17.4` to `1.18.0`. 
reverting it solved it for me (not sure why)

this was python 3.6 on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. All the already given answers did not work. I tried downgrading numpy versions as well, as it was said to work at some other forum

I eventually reinstalled Anaconda and then installed pip installed xgboost again. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the correct version of xgboost and sklearn. Then after installing on Jupyter notebook. you will see it is not working just restart your jupyter notebook. I solved using this way from this source:

https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/9e5adeeb-f57f-4283-8989-d213d7c61864/y says:
Ran into the same issue, I had installed sklearn after installing xgboost while my jupyter notebook was running. By restarting my Jupyter notebook server, xgboost was able to find the sklearn installation.