# Anaconda issues with py-xgboost and sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, xgboost

I have Anaconda 5.3.0 Winx86 installed. I installed xgboost package using
`conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost`
In Jupyter Notebook, I am able to import XGBRegressor
`from xgboost import XGBRegressor` 
But when I use `xgb = XGBRegressor()`. I get the following error:

```
XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-99b3db9fba2c> in <module>
----> 1 xgb = XGBRegressor()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in __init__(self, max_depth, learning_rate, n_estimators, silent,objective,nthread, gamma, min_child_weight, max_delta_step, subsample, colsample_bytree, colsample_bylevel, reg_alpha, reg_lambda, scale_pos_weight, base_score, seed, missing)
119                  base_score=0.5, seed=0, missing=None):
120         if not SKLEARN_INSTALLED:
--> 121     raise XGBoostError('sklearn needs to be installed in order to use this module')
122         self.max_depth = max_depth
123         self.learning_rate = learning_rate

XGBoostError: sklearn needs to be installed in order to use this module
```

But I am able to import sklearn module without any error:
`import sklearn`. I tried reinstalling both anaconda and xgboost but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Install sklearn using pip.

```
sudo pip install sklearn
```

Now import XGBRegressor in the code:

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor
```

Comment: I already have sklearn installed, I checked in the packages too and I can import it to jupyter notebook as well. I still tried to do what you said, but getting the same error. Looks like some kind of version issue but not sure with what

Comment: Do you have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed in your system?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353243/xgboost-cant-find-sklearn Have you checked this?

Comment: I have python 3 installed. Yes, I did research enough before asking the question here, the solution mentioned didn't work for me.

Comment: I am not using PyCharm on my pc

Comment: Well, then you can try it. Maybe it will work there.